# Is there a good way to use VPC service controls in a multi-departmental GCP organization

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I have a question about VPC Service Control ("VSC") in GCP.

Let's say you have a company with multiple departments and you want to create an "organization" on the GCP and use a "VSC" for each department.

In this case, is it possible to restrict "service boundary" so that only "service boundary" of the GCP project that each department handles independently can be set?

I think it depends on the department what kind of IP restrictions they put on BigQuery, so if only the information systems department can change the VSC, I think it will make it less usable.
I asked if there was a better way to do this because it's not good for each department's personnel to be able to change the settings in other departments.

Answer (score 1):

You might use Access levels, According with the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/service-perimeters#grant_access_from_outside_a_service_perimeter_using_access_levels)
Using access levels, you can specify public IP CIDR blocks, and individual user and service accounts that you want to permit to access resources protected by VPC Service Controls.

Also I have found an [example](https://cloud.google.com/access-context-manager/docs/create-basic-access-level#corporate-network-example) that describes how to create an access level condition that allows access only from a specified range of IP addresses

In this way when you create your service perimeter you can choose the access level that you already created.

Here you have a [guide](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/create-service-perimeters#creating_a_service_perimeter) to create a service perimeter.

You can also add access levels [after a perimeter has been created](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/use-access-levels).

Answer (score 0):

Configuring VPC Service control is based on [roles at the organization level](https://cloud.google.com/vpc-service-controls/docs/access-control). This means that if you assign edit permissions to one of your users they will be able configure all service perimeters and access levels.

You can perform this set up you are describing by having multiple organizations, which in this case would be departments and assigning specific users permissions there.

Comment: thanks.As I thought it's like that...
I want to enforce the organization's policies on each project, so I don't want to have multiple organizations in-house.
However, I wanted to let you use only the IP restriction function freely in each project, but it seems not to be possible at the moment.

Comment: You can set up IP restrictions in each project, by setting up an access level based on IP address and setting the condition to false.

Comment: Sorry, but I want each person to be able to set IP restrictions on their own projects only.